# Parsing rows (`\\`) and tab characters (`&`)

Tags: tables, macros, expansion, parsing

I have a use for parsing what would look like `tabular` input data, except that it isn't part of a `tabular` environment, but rather the argument to a macro.  So I developed two macros, `\readTABrow` which will read a `&` separated list into different tokens, and `\readMANYrows` which will read a `\\` separated list into many tokens.

Each of these two macros behaves as expected, when I pass it arguments that would otherwise appear in a `tabular` "row" or "table".  The problem comes when I take the output from `\readMANYrows`, which gives me one token per row, each populated with `&`-separated data, and I pass that token to `\readTABrow` in an effort to further parse a tabular row into individual cell data.

I'm suspecting that somehow, the "nature" of the `&` characters change when being parsed by `readMANYrows` and that they no longer look like tab separators by the time they reach `\readTABrow`.

My question is how to preserve the tab "nature" of the `&` characters during a `\readMANYrows`, so that I can pass the token containing them straight to `\readTABrow` without a problem.

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ifthen}

\makeatletter

% FOR PROCESSING A &-SEPARATED ROW 
\newcounter{TABcellindex@}

\newcommand\readTABrow[2]{%
  \def\doneTABread{F}%
  \def\postTAB{#2}%
  \setcounter{TABcellindex@}{0}%
  \whiledo{\equal{\doneTABread}{F}}{%
    \stepcounter{TABcellindex@}%
    \expandafter\processTAB\postTAB&\\%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{\preTAB}{}}{%
      \addtocounter{TABcellindex@}{-1}%
      \def\doneTABread{T}%
    }{%
      \expandafter\protected@edef\csname #1X\roman{TABcellindex@}\endcsname{%
        \preTAB}%
    }%
  }%
% \#1TABcells GIVES HOW MANY TAB COLUMNS WERE PROCESSED
  \expandafter\xdef\csname #1TABcells\endcsname{\arabic{TABcellindex@}}%
}

\def\processTAB#1&#2\\{%
  \protected@edef\preTAB{#1}%
  \protected@edef\postTAB{#2}%
}

% FOR PROCESSING A \\-SEPARATED GROUP OF ROWS
\newcounter{ROWcellindex@}

\newcommand\readMANYrows[2]{%
  \def\doneROWread{F}%
  \def\postROW{#2\\}%
  \setcounter{ROWcellindex@}{0}%
  \whiledo{\equal{\doneROWread}{F}}{%
    \stepcounter{ROWcellindex@}%
    \expandafter\processROW\postROW||%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{\postROW}{}}{%
      \def\doneROWread{T}%
    }{}%
    \expandafter\protected@edef\csname #1X\roman{ROWcellindex@}\endcsname{%
      \preROW}%
  }%
% \#1ROWs GIVES HOW MANY ROWS WERE PROCESSED
  \expandafter\xdef\csname #1ROWs\endcsname{\arabic{ROWcellindex@}}%
}

\def\processROW#1\\#2||{%
  \protected@edef\preROW{#1}%
  \protected@edef\postROW{#2}%
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}
\verb|\readTABrow| Input: \verb|{a&b&c&d}|
\readTABrow{myrow}{a&b&c&d}\par
.\myrowXi.\par
.\myrowXii.\par
.\myrowXiii.\par
.\myrowXiv.\par
COLUMNS: \myrowTABcells\par
---

\verb|\readMANYrows| Input: \verb|{a&b&c&d\\b\\\\ c}|
\readMANYrows{mydata}{a&b&c&d\\b\\\\ c}\par
.\detokenize\expandafter{\mydataXi}.(detokenized)\par
.\mydataXii.\par
.\mydataXiii.\par
.\mydataXiv.\par
ROWS: \mydataROWs\par
---

\verb|\readTABrow| Input: \verb|\mydataXi|
\readTABrow{mydataXi}{\mydataXi}\par
.\detokenize\expandafter{\mydataXiXi}.(detokenized)\par
COLUMNS:\mydataXiTABcells\par

\end{document}
```

The output, given below, shows individual cases of `\readTABrow` and `\readMANYrows` working as I expected, while the last example shows that `\readTABrow`, when passed a token produced by `\readMANYrows`, erroneously determines the token to be `&` free, composed of a single cell, rather than being composed of 4 cells

[image]

**Note that the use of `\detokenize` is merely as a debugging aid to display the contents of various macros that contain `&` characters.  No `\detokenize`d data is passed to `\readTABrow`.**

On a related side note, is it traditional when parsing `&` and `\\` markers to ignore the spaces following them or not?  As you see from my MWE, I do not ignore them.

**UPDATE:**

David Carlisle solved the problem, though he still isn't quite sure what I want with it.  So, let me show it.  If the last lines of the MWE are replaced with

```
\verb|\readTABrow| Input: \verb|\mydataXi|
\def\foo{\readTABrow{mydataXi}}
\expandafter\foo\expandafter{\mydataXi}\par
.\mydataXiXi.\par
.\mydataXiXii.\par
.\mydataXiXiii.\par
.\mydataXiXiv.\par
COLUMNS:\mydataXiTABcells\par
```

the final output becomes

[image]

Thus, with David's help, I can use my two routines to take a tabular like argument like

```
{a&b&c\\d&e&f\\g&h&i}
```

and store the table components as if I had typed elements of an array:

```
\edef\mydataXiXi{a}
\edef\mydataXiXii{b}
\edef\mydataXiXiii{c}
\edef\mydataXiiXi{d}
\edef\mydataXiiXii{e}
\edef\mydataXiiXiii{f}
\edef\mydataXiiiXi{g}
\edef\mydataXiiiXii{h}
\edef\mydataXiiiXiii{i}
```

which is amenable to accessing via `\csname mydataX\roman{row}X\roman{col}\endcsname`

This will be useful when the output associated with the argument must be split up (horizontally across pages) or spliced (merged with other data), or if individual cells need to be later recalled.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm still unclear what output you need, but in the last call you are not passing a `&` separated list, you are passing a macro that expands to such a list, so you need to expand it first.

```
\def\foo{\readTABrow{mydataXi}}
\expandafter\foo\expandafter{\mydataXi}\par
.\detokenize\expandafter{\mydataXiXi}.(detokenized)\par
COLUMNS:\mydataXiTABcells\par
```

produces COLUMNS:4 rather than COLUMNS:1

As for the related question, if you are trying to emulate the normal TeX `\halign` behaviour, spaces are not dropped by the parser, so space tokens are generated, but LaTeX always avoids typesetting any white space resulting from such as each cell preamble starts with `\ignorespaces` and ends with `\unskip` if it's in hmode.

Comment: That's it!  See update to question as to how I want to use it.

Answer (score 2):

I don't like to reinvent the wheel; with LaTeX3 macros it's quite easy. Note the *-variant for expanding the argument if given as a control sequence expanding to the required token list. It could be dispensed with if you have full control over the tokens that can appear in your input, that is, if they are only unexpandable tokens (but one has to be careful with a leading `\\`, of course).

There's some code duplication, so the macros could be simplified.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\readTABrow}{ s m m }
 {
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}
   { \segle_read_tab_row:no { #2 } { #3 } }
   { \segle_read_tab_row:nn { #2 } { #3 } }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\readMANYrows}{ s m m }
 {
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}
   { \segle_read_many_rows:no { #2 } { #3 } }
   { \segle_read_many_rows:nn { #2 } { #3 } }
 }

\seq_new:N \l_segle_row_seq
\seq_new:N \l_segle_manyrows_seq
\int_new:N \l_segle_row_int
\int_new:N \l_segle_manyrows_int
\cs_new_protected:Npn \segle_read_tab_row:nn #1 #2
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_segle_row_seq { & } { #2 }
  \int_zero:N \l_segle_row_int
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_segle_row_seq
   {
    \int_incr:N \l_segle_row_int
    \cs_set:cpn { #1 X \int_to_roman:n { \l_segle_row_int } } { ##1 }
   }
  \cs_set:cpx { #1 TABcells } { \int_to_arabic:n { \l_segle_row_int } }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \segle_read_tab_row:nn { no }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \segle_read_many_rows:nn #1 #2
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_segle_manyrows_seq { \\ } { #2 }
  \int_zero:N \l_segle_manyrows_int
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_segle_manyrows_seq
   {
    \int_incr:N \l_segle_manyrows_int
    \cs_set:cpn { #1 X \int_to_roman:n { \l_segle_manyrows_int } } { ##1 }
   }
  \cs_set:cpx { #1 ROWs } { \int_to_arabic:n { \l_segle_manyrows_int } }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \segle_read_many_rows:nn { no }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\verb|\readTABrow| Input: \verb|{a&b&c&d}|
\readTABrow{myrow}{a&b&c&d}\par
.\myrowXi.\par
.\myrowXii.\par
.\myrowXiii.\par
.\myrowXiv.\par
COLUMNS: \myrowTABcells\par

\verb|\readMANYrows| Input: \verb|{a&b&c&d\\b\\\\ c}|
\readMANYrows{mydata}{a&b&c&d\\b\\\\ c}\par
.\detokenize\expandafter{\mydataXi}.\par
.\mydataXii.\par
.\mydataXiii.\par
.\mydataXiv.\par
ROWS: \mydataROWs\par

---

\verb|\readTABrow| Input: \verb|\mydataXi|
\readTABrow*{mydataXi}{\mydataXi}\par
.\detokenize\expandafter{\mydataXiXi}.(detokenized)\par
COLUMNS:\mydataXiTABcells\par
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Sometimes reinventing the wheel is a good learning tool.  But your point is well taken.  Are you implying that the wheel you present here is the way LaTeX digests tabular data?  Thanks for the makeover.  Now I just need to learn how to "read" LaTeX3...

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes No, `\halign` (the TeX primitive underlying `tabular`) works in a very different way: certainly not splitting the input at `&` or ``\\``, which might be hidden in macros or be different tokens altogether. The wheels I was referring to are the features of standard `expl3` functions.

Comment: "which might be hidden in macros or be different tokens altogether" -- of course... I should have known that.  It's the catcode that makes the tab character, not the glyph itself.