# \centering breaks fragile command (is there a fix?)

Tags: macros, tex-core

Many on this site know (and perhaps find slightly annoying) that I will try to solve any LaTeX problem with the use of my `stackengine` package.  My motto is like one of the overnight delivery services: "if it stacks, we ship it".

I found an odd problem in one of my parsing routines from that package, and I know it very much relates to the topic or robustness (which I kind of understand in theory, but certainly don't know enough to overcome).  What I found surprising is that this particular problem only arises after an invocation of `\centering` which I found quite odd and unexpected.

I've boiled the problem down to this MWE.  Here, `\@readMANYrows` will take an argument consisting of multi-row data, each row separated by a "end-of-line" (EOL) character, and parse it into individual row data.  The `stackengine` package, for historical reasons, defaults this EOL character to a space, but has a package option to make the EOL a `\\` to be more in line with what LaTeX users might expect (I realize `\\` is a macro, not a character, and that perhaps is the root of this problem).

When the EOL is set to `\\`, everything works fine.  If `\centering` is invoked, however, the routine will only work if the EOL is something other than `\\`.  Finally, if I make `\protect\\` the EOL, everything works again even when centering, but that last syntax is really a nuisance and for academic interest only.

So my question is two-fold:  I am curious how it is that `\centering` undermines the parsing routine (it is not as if `\centering` is an argument to my routine... it is not)?; AND, is there an easy way to make the parsing routine robust without, for example, rewriting it in LaTeX3, as egreg did at [Parsing rows (`\\`) and tab characters (`&`)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/131581/parsing-rows-and-tab-characters)?

I would only add, as a postscript, that `\usepackage{fixltx2e}` does not resolve this problem.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\newcounter{ROWcellindex@}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\setstackEOL[1]{%
  \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{}}{\def\SEP@char{ }}{\def\SEP@char{#1}}%
  \expandafter\define@processROW\expandafter{\SEP@char}%
}

\newcommand\define@processROW[1]{%
    \def\@processROW##1#1##2||{%
      \protected@edef\@preSEP{##1}%
      \protected@edef\@postSEP{##2}%
    }%
}

% FOR PROCESSING A GROUP OF STACK ROWS SEPARATED BY \SEP@char
\newcommand\@readMANYrows[1]{%
  \def\@doneROWreads{F}%
  \def\@postSEP{#1\SEP@char}%
  \setcounter{ROWcellindex@}{0}%
  \whiledo{\equal{\@doneROWreads}{F}}{%
    \stepcounter{ROWcellindex@}%
    \expandafter\@processROW\@postSEP||%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{\@postSEP}{}}{%
      \def\@doneROWreads{T}%
    }{}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{\SEP@char}{ }}%
      {\def\@preSEPtemp{\@preSEP}}%
      {\def\@preSEPtemp{\ignorespaces\@preSEP\unskip}}%
    \expandafter\protected@edef\csname arg\roman{ROWcellindex@}\endcsname{%
      \@preSEPtemp}%
  }%
% \narg GIVES HOW MANY ROWS WERE PROCESSED
  \xdef\narg{\arabic{ROWcellindex@}}%
}
\begin{document}

% OK IF NO CENTERING
\setstackEOL{\\}
\@readMANYrows{a \\ b \\ c}
\argi, \argii, \argiii\\

% OK IF DIFFERENT EOL CHARACTER
\centering
\setstackEOL{$}
\@readMANYrows{d $ e $ f}
\argi, \argii, \argiii\\

% BREAKS! \\ NOT ROBUST
%\centering
%\setstackEOL{\\}
%\@readMANYrows{g \\ h \\ i}
%\argi, \argii, \argiii\\

% PROTECTING \\ WORKS, BUT IS A NUISANCE TO USE
\centering
\setstackEOL{\protect\\}
\@readMANYrows{j \protect\\ k \protect\\ l}
\argi, \argii, \argiii\\

\end{document}
```

Comment: The main difference is that in normal context ``\\`` is a robust command, but it isn't in the scope of `\centering`. My impression is that you're passing it in a `\protected@edef` and this would explain the problem. Why you're passing the row delimiter to `\protected@edef` in the first place is not clear. And the use of `\protected@edef` when splitting is questionable too, I believe.

Comment: Note that `\\ ` is redefined all over the place: `center` `raggedright` `tabbing` `tabular`  anyway you are only using the sepchar as a separator so you may as well locally   `\let` it to `\relax` so it is always robust.

Comment: @egreg I had thought the `\protected@edef` was only adulterating the row data, and not the EOL, but I see now from the recursive nature of `\@readMANYrows` that downstream `\SEP@char`s become part of `\@postSEP`, and thus get expanded.  And since you point out (I didn't know) that `\\\` ` is not robust with `\centering`, I think I understand now why it breaks.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I understand what you are saying, and I am continuing my feeble attempts to figure out where locally to do that.

Comment: easiest thing actually is probably to document the sepchar has to be a single token and then change your set command so instead of `\def\SEP@char{#1}}` it does `\def\SEP@char{\protect#1}}`  but as egreg commented you probably shouldn't be using edef anyway, then it wouldn't be an issue.

Comment: Actually ``\\`` doesn't survive `\ifthenelse{\equal{\\}{}}` when it has the definition in `\centering`, which is the first problem. You really should use more robust tests, for instance those in `etoolbox`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With the redefinition performed by `\centering`, also `\ifthenelse{\equal{\\}{}}{true}{false}` fails, because `\equal` performs full expansion. This has no consequence with the default definition, because it's done with `\DeclareRobustCommand`. Surely you should also avoid `\protected@edef` where possible.

You are better off using more powerful and robust tests. I'd go with LaTeX3, but `etoolbox` also has many helpful features.

Here's an implementation with `etoolbox`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newcounter{ROWcellindex@}
\newtoggle{@doneROWreads}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\setstackEOL[1]{%
  \ifstrempty{#1}{\def\SEP@char{ }}{\def\SEP@char{#1}}%
  \expandafter\define@processROW\expandafter{\SEP@char}%
}

\newcommand\define@processROW[1]{%
    \def\@processROW##1#1##2||{%
      \def\@preSEP{##1}%
      \def\@postSEP{##2}%
    }%
}

% FOR PROCESSING A GROUP OF STACK ROWS SEPARATED BY \SEP@char
\newcommand\@readMANYrows[1]{%
  \togglefalse{@doneROWreads}%
  \edef\@postSEP{\unexpanded{#1}\expandonce{\SEP@char}}%
  \setcounter{ROWcellindex@}{0}%
  \whileboolexpr{test {\nottoggle{@doneROWreads}}}{%
    \stepcounter{ROWcellindex@}%
    \expandafter\@processROW\@postSEP||%
    \expandafter\ifstrempty\expandafter{\@postSEP}{%
      \toggletrue{@doneROWreads}%
    }{}%
    \expandafter\ifstrequal\expandafter{\SEP@char}{ }%
      {}%
      {\edef\@preSEP{\ignorespaces\expandonce{\@preSEP}\unskip}}%
    \csedef{arg\roman{ROWcellindex@}}{\expandonce{\@preSEP}}%
  }%
% \narg GIVES HOW MANY ROWS WERE PROCESSED
  \xdef\narg{\arabic{ROWcellindex@}}%
}
\begin{document}

% OK IF NO CENTERING
\setstackEOL{\\}
\@readMANYrows{a \\ b \\ c}
\argi, \argii, \argiii

% OK IF DIFFERENT EOL CHARACTER
\centering

\setstackEOL{$}
\@readMANYrows{d $ e $ f}
\argi, \argii, \argiii\\

% BREAKS! \\ NOT ROBUST
\centering
\setstackEOL{\\}
\@readMANYrows{g \\ h \\ i}
\argi, \argii, \argiii

% PROTECTING \\ WORKS, BUT IS A NUISANCE TO USE
\centering
\setstackEOL{\protect\\}
\@readMANYrows{j \protect\\ k \protect\\ l}
\argi, \argii, \argiii

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Your ability to digest bad code and fix it on the fly is much appreciated.  And I can readily understand this syntax (unlike LaTeX3), and will use this example to enrich my learning.  Not only did you fix the issue of fragile EOL separators, but as a by-product you fixed the issue of fragile arguments in `\Shortstack`, `\Shortundertack`, `\Longstack` and `\Longunderstack`.  I am very grateful.  This will without doubt go into the next package release.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes You're welcome. Once you master `etoolbox` facilities, going to LaTeX3 shouldn't be difficult. ;-)